# Como fazer campo de busca CSS e HTML

Tags: php, html, css, algoritmo-de-busca

Olá boa tarde gostaria de tirar umas duvidas estou começando a aprender agora , estou com um problema pra criar um campo de busca no meu site , gostaria de uma ajuda .

Gostaria de colocar esse sistema de pesquisa [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No topo do meu site que seria esse [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sou iniciante na área quem poder me ajudar agradeceria muito !!!

Código CSS :

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
font-family:Calibri;
font-size:30px;
line-height:36px;
color:rgb(255,255,255);
text-align:left;
}

#topo {
 background:url(../imagens/topo.png); 
 width:1024px;
 height:190px;
 border-bottom:none;
 margin:auto;
 
}

.logo {
 float:left;
 background:url(../imagens/logoc.png);
 width:541px;
 height:133px;
 position:relative;
 margin:40px 0 0 -4px;

}

Código HTML Abaixo
```

```html
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/estilo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>


<body>
<div id ="topo">
<div = class="logo"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Obrigado Pela Atenção !!! Abraços

Comment: Colocar em baixo do lado direito

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form action="">
    <input class="Busca-texto" type="text"> //Campo de busca
</form>

<style>
    .Busca-texto{
        width: 200px; //Largura do campo
        height: 35px; //Altura do campo
        float: right; //Posição do campo
        background-image: url('img/ic_search_white_24dp_1x.png'); //diretório e imagem do icone 
        background-position: left;  //posição do icone
        background-repeat: no-repeat; //Não repetir o icone <- COLOCA ISSO PELO AMOR DE ODIN
        background-color: #fff; //Cor do fundo do campo
        border: 2px solid #000; //Cor da borda do campo
        border-radius: 4px; //Curvatura da borda nas "quinas"
        text-indent: 25px; //Um espaçamento para n atrapalhar a img
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Eu coloco no CSS ou no index do HTML ? estou com essa duvida

Comment: no HTML. a tag style faz com que você possa adicionar css dentro dela.

mas se você quiser separar o HTML do css, basta copiar o css sem as tag <style></style> e colar no seu arquivo css

Comment: Entendi só to meio perdido no <form action="">
    <input class="Busca-texto" type="text"> //Campo de busca
</form> , mais vou tentar aqui muito obrigado pela ajuda !! abraço

Comment: Consegui , só não consigo poscionar ele no lugar que eu quero , mas muito obrigado pela ajuda !!!

Comment: quando você cria um formulário de peenchimento, você tem que colocar esse "<form>" e mais algumas coisas que vai dentro dele, para ele fazer a ligação com PHP, ir para a página de resultado e etc. o campo <input type="text"> e padrão para fazer um campo de peenchimo. você pode fazer outros tipos de campo com input, botão, caixa de marcar opções, campo de colocar texto dentre outras coisas.

esses 2 vão no HTML. e de nada ^^